# Why not just make non-parameterized queries return an error?

Tags: security, sql, rdbms

SQL injection is a very serious security issue, in large part because it's so easy to get it wrong: the obvious, intuitive way to build a query incorporating user input leaves you vulnerable, and the Right Way to mitigate it requires you to know about parameterized queries and SQL injection first.

Seems to me that the obvious way to fix this would be to shut down the obvious (but wrong) option: fix the database engine so that any query received that uses hard-coded values in its WHERE clause instead of parameters returns a nice, descriptive error message instructing you to use parameters instead.  This would obviously need to have an opt-out option so that stuff like ad-hoc queries from administrative tools will still run easily, but it should be enabled by default.

Having this would shut down SQL injection cold, almost overnight, but as far as I know, no RDBMS actually does this.  Is there any good reason why not?

Comment: `bad_ideas_sql = 'SELECT title FROM idea WHERE idea.status == "bad" AND idea.user == :mwheeler'` would have both hard-coded and parameterized values in a single query – try to catch that! I think there are valid use cases for such mixed queries.

Comment: How about selecting records from today `SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY score DESC;`

Comment: @amon: Try to catch that? Easy: `if (WhereClauses.OfType<BinaryExpression>().Any(be => !IsParameterized(be))) NeedParameterizedQueryError();`  Why is that supposed to be difficult to catch?

Comment: @MasonWheeler sorry, I meant “try to allow that”. Note that it is perfectly parameterized and does not suffer from SQL injection. However, the database driver cannot tell whether the literal `"bad"` is truly literal or resulted from string concatenation. The two solutions I see are either getting rid of SQL and other string-embedded DSLs  (yes please), or promoting languages where string concatenation is more annoying than using parameterized queries (umm, no).

Comment: @amon: The whole point is *not* to allow that, because even if it's "OK" in its current form, how do we know that in the next update, the requirements won't change and allow the status value to come from user input?

Comment: and how would the RDBMS detect whether to do this? It would overnight make it impossible to access the RDBMS using an interactive SQL prompt... You'd no longer be able to enter DDL or DML commands using any tool at all.

Comment: @MasonWheeler if it changes in future so that the status comes from user input, switch it to a parameter then. Unless and until thar happens, the hard coded value is the correct option. Using a parameter for something that never varies is misleading, hence bad style.

Comment: @jwenting: That's exactly the use case where I specifically said there should be an opt-out for.  Your interactive prompt (or SQL management tool) would set that so you can run ad-hoc queries in peace.

Comment: A better solution is to use [tainted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking) strings for user input, so that concatenation with unprocessed user input results in a tainted string that a DB driver refuses to accept as a query. I remember successfully using Java annotations to achieve such an effect.

Comment: @jwenting it could be a connection option that must be explicitly enabled or disabled.

Comment: What do you mean RDBMS  catch?  Where is this WhereClauses.OfType?    Even if the RDBMS can catch it I don't want it to.  I am a big enough boy to know when I need to use parameterized queries and the are lots of time I don't need to.  Maybe no RDBMS does this for good reasons.

Comment: @Frisbee: Pride goeth before the fall.  The reason why decades-old errors like SQL injection and buffer overruns keep getting exploited over and over and over is because they're way too easy of mistakes to make, even for "big boys" who do know better.  (Just look at Heartbleed. It was caused by an amateur mistake, but the coder who made it was no amateur!)

Comment: SQL injection bad = lock it all down ?   You asked a question and got an answer.   Now it is my pride that stops me from understanding your wisdom?

Comment: In a sense you can do this: don't construct SQL queries at runtime at all, instead use an ORM or some other abstraction layer that avoids you needing to construct SQL queries. ORM doesn't have the features you need? Then SQL is a language intended for people who want to write SQL, which is why on the whole it lets them write SQL. The fundamental issue is that dynamically generating code is harder than it looks, but people want to do it anyway and will be unsatisfied with products that don't let them.

Comment: @amon: I suppose the simple answer is that you would rewrite your query as `SELECT title FROM idea WHERE idea.status == :bad AND idea.user == :mwheeler` and set the parameter `bad = "bad"`, thus letting the DB connector do the terrifying work of correctly SQL-quoting the string `bad` for you. Making your code slightly more verbose and slightly less readable in order to satisfy some automated enforcement of "safer code" is what e.g. explicit static types are all about, so you'd get used to it :-)

Comment: Using "taint" checking like in Perl will find that, @amon.  In fact tainting will make sure you pass *only* the literal strings for the query and never interpolate into it,  so the SQL engine need to get involved.

Comment: I worked on a project where store procedure were mandatory. They passed all variable through parameter of store proc. Sound good right? Inside the store proc, all query were dynamically created and each parameters were concatenated!

Just to say, without proper education people will find ways.

Answer (score 45):

There are too many cases where using a literal is the right approach.

From a performance standpoint, there are times that you want literals in your queries.  Imagine I have a bug tracker where once it gets big enough to worry about performance I expect that 70% of the bugs in the system will be "closed", 20% will be "open", 5% will be "active" and 5% will be in some other status.  I may reasonably want to have the query that returns all active bugs to be

```
SELECT *
  FROM bug
 WHERE status = 'active'
```

rather than passing the `status` as a bind variable.  I want a different query plan depending on the value passed in for `status`-- I'd want to do a table scan to return the closed bugs and an index scan on the `status` column to return the active loans.  Now, different databases and different versions have different approaches to (more or less successfully) allow the same query to use a different query plan depending on the value of the bind variable.  But that tends to introduce a decent amount of complexity that needs to be managed to balance out the decision of whether to bother re-parsing a query or whether to reuse an existing plan for a new bind variable value. For a developer, it may make sense to deal with this complexity.  Or it may make sense to force a different path when I have more information about what my data is going to look like than the optimizer does.

From a code complexity standpoint, there are also plenty of times that it makes perfect sense to have literals in SQL statements.  For example, if you have a `zip_code` column that has a 5 character zip code and sometimes has an additional 4 digits, it makes perfect sense to do something like

```
SELECT substr( zip_code, 1, 5 ) zip,
       substr( zip_code, 7, 4 ) plus_four
```

rather than passing in 4 separate parameters for the numeric values.  These aren't things that will ever change so making them bind variables only serves to make the code potentially more difficult to read and to create the potential that someone will bind parameters in the wrong order and end up with a bug.

Answer (score 12):

SQL injection occurs when a query is built by concatenating text from an untrusted and unvalidated source with other portions of a query.  While such a thing would most often occur with string literals, that would not be the only way it could occur.  A query for numeric values might take a user-entered string (that's *supposed* to only contain digits) and concatenate with other material to form a query without the quote marks normally associated with string literals; code which is overly trusting of client-side validation might have things like field names come from an HTML query string.  There's no way code looking at an SQL query string can see how it was assembled.

What's important is not whether an SQL statement contains string literals, but rather whether a string contains any *sequences of characters from untrusted sources*, and validation for that would be best handled in the library which builds queries.  There's generally no way in C# to write code that will allow a string literal but won't allow other kinds of string expression, but one could have a coding-practices rule that requires that queries be built up using a query-building class rather than string concatenation, and anyone passing a non-literal string to the query builder must justify such action.

Comment: As an approximation for "is it a literal" you can check if the string is interned.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: True, and such a test might be accurate enough for this purpose, provided that anyone who had a reason for generating a string at runtime used a method which accepted a non-literal string rather than interning the runtime-generated string and using that (giving the non-literal-string method a different name would make it easy for code reviewers to inspect all uses of it).

Comment: Note that while there's no way of doing this in C#, some other languages do have facilities that make it possible (e.g. Perl's tainted string module).

Comment: More succinctly, this is a _client_ problem, not a server problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT count(ID)
FROM posts
WHERE deleted = false
```

If you want to put the results of these in the footer of your forum you would need to add a dummy parameter just to say false every time. Or the naive web programmer looks up how to disable that warning and then continues on.

Now you can say you would add an exception for enums but that just opens the hole again (though smaller). Not to mention people first need to be educated to not use `varchars` for those.

The real problem of injection is programmatically constructing the query string. The solution for that is a stored procedure mechanism and enforcing its use or a whitelist of allowed queries.

Comment: If your solution for "it's all too easy to forget--or not know in the first place--to use parametrized queries" is "make everyone remember--and know in the first place--to use stored procs", then you're missing the entire point of the question.

Comment: I've seen SQL injection via stored procedures at my work. It turns out mandating stored procedures for everything is BAD. There's always that 0.5% that are true dynamic queries (you can't parametrize an entire where clause, let alone a table join).

Comment: In the example in this answer you could replace `deleted = false` with `NOT deleted`, which avoids the literal. But the point is valid in general.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: You'd have to restrict *all* literals, not just the ones in `WHERE` clauses. For reasons why they don't, it allows the database to remain decoupled from other systems.

Firstly, your premise is flawed. You want to restrict only `WHERE` clauses, but that's not the only place user input can go. For example,

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_type = 'blender' THEN 1 END) as type1_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_type = 'television' THEN 1 END) AS type2_count)
FROM item
```

This is equally vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_type = 'blender' THEN 1 END) FROM item; DROP TABLE user_info; SELECT CASE(WHEN item_type = 'blender' THEN 1 END) as type1_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_type = 'television' THEN 1 END) AS type2_count)
FROM item
```

So you can't just restrict literals in the `WHERE` clause. You have to restrict *all* literals.

Now we're left with the question, "Why allow literals at all?" Keep this in mind: while relational databases are used underneath an application written in another language a large percentage of the time, there is no *requirement* that you must use application code to use the database. And here we have an answer: you need literals to write code. The only other alternative would be to require all code to be written in some language independent of the database. So having them gives you the ability to write "code" (SQL) directly in the database. This is a valuable decoupling, and it would be impossible without literals. (Try writing in your favorite language sometime without literals. I'm sure you can imagine how difficult this would be.)

As a common example, literals are often used in the population of list-of-value/look-up tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (role_id INTEGER, role_name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO user_roles (1, 'normal');
INSERT INTO user_roles (2, 'admin');
INSERT INTO user_roles (3, 'banned');
```

Without them, you would need to write code in *another programming language* just to populate this table. The ability to do so directly in SQL is *valuable*.

We're then left with one more question: why don't programming language client libraries do it then? And here we have a very simple answer: they would have ***re-implement the entire database parser*** for each supported version of the database. Why? Because there's no other way to guarantee you've found every literal. Regular expressions aren't enough. For example: this contains 4 separate literals in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT $lit1$I'm a literal$lit1$||$lit2$I'm another literal $$ with nested string delimiters$$ $lit2$||'I''m ANOTHER literal'||$$I'm the last literal$$;
```

Trying to do that would be a maintenance nightmare, especially since valid syntax often changes between major releases of databases.